# New to ActionScript 3.0 - Got some questions with IF statements and text boxes

Tags: flash, actionscript, event-handling

Let's say I'm creating a game where you can edit character skills.

For now, there is only the "**endurance**" valuable, which is 10. You can decrease it, but I want it to stop at 5 (as a hero with 0 or negative endurance would be meaningless).

**I have two questions**, but let's look at the code first:

```
//Defaults
var hero_endurance:int = 10;
var string_hero_endurance:String = String(hero_endurance);
box_hero_endurance.text = string_hero_endurance;
//Endurance Controls
function hero_endurance_decrease(MouseEvent):void {
    hero_endurance = hero_endurance-1;
    var string_hero_endurance:String = String(hero_endurance);
    box_hero_endurance.text = string_hero_endurance;
}
if (hero_endurance > 5){
button_hero_endurance_down.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hero_endurance_decrease);
}
```

Now my first question:

**This code doesn't work.** The valuable keeps going down, like the if statement isn't there at all. How can I fix this?

Second question:

Maybe you have noticed, the function always refreshes the valuable in the text box by:

```
var string_hero_endurance:String = String(hero_endurance);
box_hero_endurance.text = string_hero_endurance;
```

**Actionscript 2.0 didn't even require such a code**, any change you did to a valuable would reflect in a text box. **Is there a simple way to do this, or do I have to use this code for each and every case?**

Thanks on advance!

Comment: You have bit off more than you can chew, friend. Even if you get an answer, you would certainly get more impediments and waste time waiting for others to fix your problems for you. Take O'Reilly's book on as3 and insert it into your brain.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've been using AS 2.0 for a long time and I'm not a hardcore coder. I just wish to do basic things, I'm not interested in packages or anything heavy maths/physics related. Reading a thick book for simple things isn't really my thing at the moment.

Comment: You GOT to learn to crawl before you can walk. Even more so before you run. I have been where you exactly are and I have no reason to deceive you, but that book is the minimum you need to know. Object oriented programming is extremely powerful and rejecting it is just like stabbing your own eyes so you can see better.

Comment: Appreciate the comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it keeps going down is because your listener is not set up correctly. Your event listener keeps firing even after the endurance dips below 5. Also, your event handler function declaration was not setup correctly. This is how I would do it:

```
//Defaults
var hero_endurance:int = 10;
var string_hero_endurance:String = String(hero_endurance);
box_hero_endurance.text = string_hero_endurance;

//Endurance Controls
function hero_endurance_decrease(event:MouseEvent):void {
    hero_endurance = hero_endurance-1;
    var string_hero_endurance:String = String(hero_endurance);
    box_hero_endurance.text = string_hero_endurance;

    removeEnduranceListener();
}

// removes the endurance listener when needed
function removeEnduranceListener():void {
    if (hero_endurance <= 5){
        button_hero_endurance_down.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hero_endurance_decrease);
    }
}

// adds the endurance listener when needed
function addEnduranceListener():void {
    if (hero_endurance > 5){
        button_hero_endurance_down.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hero_endurance_decrease);
    }
}

addEnduranceListener();  // add the endurance listener (function adds if needed)
```

The most important thing in my code above is that wherever you allow for their endurance to be increased, you need to add a call to the addEnduranceListener function so that the listener to decrease their endurance gets registered again, and using my code as a template, you can create functions in a similar fashion that add endurance and degregister the add endurance functionality when their endurance reaches 10.

Comment: I just modified my code a bit more and updated my answer.  Strange it keeps going down.  I'm starting up Flash CC right now and going to debug it. give me a minute.

Comment: yea, I just caught that and fixed it, my post is already updated

Comment: so other than that one typo, I ran my code and it worked as I thought it would.  the endurance counter stops at 5.

Comment: do you have any other code that adds event listeners or has to do with how their endurance attribute is modified?

Comment: Great job indeed! Thanks. Yet it kinda hurts to do so much coding for such a little thing, imagine now I have to create a button to **increase** the same variable, and add new skills like strenght, luck etc...

Comment: oh the increase button is easy!  I wired that up in my .fla file just to make sure it works, let me give you that code. give me a minute.

Comment: Increasing is limited with "remaining skill points", as it would be in a typical role playing game. Say, can I reach you some other way (mail, pm etc)? I promise I won't bother you much and my questions will be rather easy :) My aim is to create this game with the simplest ways possible.

Comment: Ahhh ok, I won't finish coding that part up then because it probably won't fit your needs.

Comment: If you wish to contact, add me on face book, just look me up by my name "Anil Natha" and send me a message on FB.  I'd rather not publish my email on this site.

Comment: But I'll probably know how to do it from now on; I know it's about event listeners. Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome. I understand your hesitation at going through and learning all there is to AS3, but if you do, you will find it will actually make your coding job much _easier_ because you will gain and understanding of all the great features of AS3.  The API is there to help you write code in a more structured manner, thereby making it _much_ easier to understand.  The hardest part of AS3 is learning Object Oriented Programming, that is what usually gives people the most trouble, everything else is easy to follow if you know OOP.

Comment: Don't know if you saw the message or not, but in case you didn't, contact me on Facebook if you have any other questions.

Comment: Yes I've seen it, I've added another stat (strenght) and I'm lost again. Probably there's a conflict with listeners now. I couldn't find you on FB but you can add me if that's okay, I'll explain over there: https://www.facebook.com/hakiki.tayfuntuna

Comment: Must have something to do with privacy... Sorry, I'll look it up and tell when it's accessible

Comment: Check again please, and thank you for you patience! :)

Comment: Strange that my answer was downvoted when it is the _correct_ answer.  I think _someone_ is jealous that their answer was not accepted and possibly annoyed that I pointed out that their answer follows a known bad practice.  Oh well, some people like using information to learn, others take it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: in your function create a variable which holds an integer value for the lowest number your hero's endurance can drop to then you need to do a check against the current value something like this:

```
var currentEndurance:int = 10;
var lowestEndurance:int = 5;

if(currentEndurance != lowestEndurance)
{
//update your textbox
}else{
//both vars are equal so don't do anything
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try... I think I understand my mistake, as for every integer, I should create a variable and I missed that fact in the if statement. Let me see if it work now.

Comment: While this does work, keeping event listeners that keep firing when they do nothing is not a good practice for optimizing code. The listened should be deregistered, and added back when needed(ie. user's endurance goes past 5 again.